# Passing data from .java to .jsp file (select)

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, html-select

I need to pass data from .java to .jsp.

I created the ArrayList for two select menu and java file where data is stored. 
Now i need pass the data from list (java file) to jsp select menu (JSP file) using loop.

JAVA file:

```
public class failureinindustryData 
{

    public List<String> print() {

        ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=1970; i < 2016; i++)
        {
            String dateString = Integer.valueOf(i).toString();

            l.add(dateString);
            System.out.println(dateString);
        }

        System.out.println(l);

     return l;

    }

    public List<String> industry(){

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Option 1");
        list.add("Option 2");

        System.out.println(list);

        return list;

    }
}
```

And my JSP file:

```
        <% request.setAttribute("list", list); %>
        <% request.setAttribute("l", l); %>


        <h3>Wyszukaj awarie w przemyśle:</h3>

        <form action="#" method="post">

        Rok: <select name="year"> 
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" varStatus="row">
           <option value="#">${item}</option>
        </c:forEach> 
        </select>

        Przemysł: <select 
        name="industry"> 
        <c:forEach items="#" var="industries"> 
            <option value="#">a</option> 
            <option value="#">b</option> 

        </c:forEach> 
        </select>
```

I don't know how i can pass this array list...
The arraylist will be larger later so must be loop there ^^

Answer (score 2):

To pass data from servlet to jsp, you have to save the data in the request object :

```
request.setAttribute("mylist", myList);
```

to read the data in jsp :

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${mylist}" varStatus="row">
   <option value="#">${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I try to make this.
And got error: list/l cannot be resolved to a variable
I edit code